# Android Admob android Manifest error

Tags: android, android-manifest, admob

I am trying to put ads into my Android application, but I'm getting a weird error.

My app launches with this in the Manifest file. But it shows an error in the emulator saying
"You must have AdActivity declared in the AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges."

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard"/>
```

Whenever I add this to the Manifest file I cannot compile.

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest part at first: you are missing a few flags in the configChanges attribute of the definition of the AdActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml. As shown in the [AdMob SDK Docs](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html) the definition needs to look like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"    
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

The second -- 
Investigated the reason is because these three attributes in the latest SDK (> = 13) support, the project properties are set with Android2.2 solution is as follows:

**a:** Upgrade ADT to download the latest SDK

**b:** the API to modify the Project Build Target Level, its value must be> = 13, I chose to Android 4.0. Modify these steps: Right-click on the item, and select Properties -> Android -> Android 4.0

**c:** Modify the the AndroidManifest.xml of the targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion value is the value of their own needs

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```

for more help [see](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_768cfa590100utbi.html)

Comment: I changed the build path to 4.0. That fixed it, the flags were ok. Thank you.